# Does ArrayList of ArrayList stores the reference?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am facing problem dealing with Arraylist of Arraylist. Whenever I clear the Arraylist al in my code, ans variable also changed. I know it is stored by reference. Any idea how to solve this problem? My code is given below:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode root) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList();
    Queue<TreeNode> myQ = new LinkedList();
    if(root == null)
        return ans;
    myQ.add(root);
    myQ.add(null);
    TreeNode temp;
    while(!myQ.isEmpty()){
        temp = myQ.remove();
        if(temp == null){
            ans.add(al);
            System.out.println("al is: " + al);
            System.out.println("    ans is: " + ans);
            al.clear();
            System.out.println("            ans is: " + ans);
            if(myQ.isEmpty())
                break;
            myQ.add(null);
        }
        else{
            al.add(temp.val);
            if(temp.left != null)
                myQ.add(temp.left);
            if(temp.right != null)
                myQ.add(temp.right);
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(ans);
    return ans;        
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "ans variable also changed"?

Comment: Add some of the sysout's where the changes of `al` and `ans` can be seen.

Comment: Could please be more precise about what the output of the two `println` of `ans` is and what you expect it to be?

Comment: Close as I can see, the only thing you ever add to ans is al.  So changing al will change the elements in ans (since they are one and the same).

Answer (score 2):

Your code creates only two ArrayLists using the `new` keyword. One stored in `ans` and the other stored in `al`. References to the second one are inserted into the first, but since it is the same object the effect is that the elements are 'shared'.

To avoid this sharing you need to create a different ArrayList for each element. Instead of clearing `al`, create a new ArrayList using `new ArrayList<Integer>()` and assign that to `al`.